# How to find the next number in a sequence whose square root is a whole number

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals, programming

I've just rephrased the question a bit.

```
S(i=1 to n) is a set of n whole numbers where Square_Root(Si) is always a whole number.
```

`Di(i=1 to n)` is a set of differences such that:
`Si+Di = Sj` where `Square_Root(Sj) is a whole number` and there `no other whole number between Si and Sj whose square root is a whole number`.

For a `random value Si`, I `need to find the Di`. 
Once I get the Di for a given Si, I can easily find the next value of D in the sequence.

I am a novice in mathematics and am writing a software program. Any help would be greatly appreciated.!

Comment: what is meant by "series of differences"?

Comment: Why not consider the sequence of squares?

Comment: Take the root of the current number. Add 1 and square it. Or in other words, if $S_{n+1} = \sqrt{S_n} +1$. If you just want the difference between them it's $2\sqrt {S_n} +1$.

Comment: The series of differences as in, as S increments to S` and so on, the value of D which is the difference between S and S` as well will change. Won't they? What I wanted to do was to find the series of D's such that I just have to add them to the series of S.

Answer (score 2):

You want to go from $k^2$ to $(k+1)^2$, so you do the following
$$
(k+1)^2 - k^2 = 2k+1,
$$
and so starting with $a_0=0$ (implies a square of $0^2=0$), the next one would be
$$
a_1 = a_0 + 2\cdot 0 + 1 = a_0 + 1 = 1\\
a_2 = a_1 + 2\cdot 1 + 1 = a_1 + 3 = 4\\
a_3 = a_2 + 2\cdot 2 + 1 = a_2 + 5 = 9
$$

This way you can generate the entire sequence.

**UPDATE**

Starting at any random value $N$ which is a perfect square, compute the square root and set $k=\sqrt{N}$, then proceed as before, with
$$
a_{k+1} = a_k+2k+1
$$

Comment: Thanks mate. But the series starts off from a random value ai. Is there a way to find the difference in that case?

Comment: @NixRam see the update